# configure custom cell method not working in Custom cell, should I use delegateS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented an `UITableView` with some custom cells for validating `UITextField`s and date pickers. I want to do an easy task but I do not why it does not work. I just want to change a `UILabel` textColor property when I check if the TextField text property is empty or not.

I initialize the customs Cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`... with this code, example:

```
  firstNameCell = (WPFirstNameCell *)[aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstNameCellIdentifier];

        if(firstNameCell == nil){
            // INIT REUSABLE CELL
            firstNameCell = [[WPFirstNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstNameCellIdentifier] ;
            [firstNameCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            firstNameCell.firstDelegate = self;
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            firstNameCell.firstnameTextField.text = firstN;
     //       firstNameCell.validLabel.text = firstValidation;
            return firstNameCell;
        }
```

Then I set create the Cell with Code:

```
@implementation WPFirstNameCell
@synthesize firstnameTextField;
@synthesize isValid, validLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        isValid = NO;
        validLabel = [[WPCustomLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 80, 30)];
        validLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        validLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        validLabel.text = @"First Name ";
        [validLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
        [self addSubview:validLabel];



        firstnameTextField = [[WPCustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 240, 30)];
        firstnameTextField.placeholder = @"your first name";
        firstnameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [firstnameTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
        firstnameTextField.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:firstnameTextField];
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        //cell.accessoryView = self.firstName;
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the viewController I have one button and before send the information it has to check if the textFields are empty or not. If the textField is empty I have to change the Color of the label.

When i press the button I call this method:

```
// This method is implemented in the viewController
    -(void)changeColorsOfLabels
    {

    //firstN is the NSString that I get from the TextField

        if(firstN]){
            [firstNameCell changeColorOfLabel:NO];
             [tableView reloadData];
        }
    }
```

In the cell I have this method for change the color:

```
-(void)changeColorOfLabel:(BOOL)isOkay
{
    if(isOkay){
        isValid = YES;
        validLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } else {
        isValid = NO;
        NSLog(@"isOK: %hhd", isOkay);
        validLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

`NSLog` is correctly called. And I can see the good output.

Comment: You have this statement: [firstNameCell changeColorOfLabel:NO]. What is firstNameCell? How is that instantiated (is this the same instance you instantiate in cellForRowAtIndexPath)? Is there only one of these WPFirstNameCells, or many?

Comment: There is only one firstNameCell, it is a global Variable of the ViewController that I instantiate in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I copied your code, and it worked for me. The only things I changed were to use the UI versions of the label and text field instead of the WPCustom versions, and I gave a value to firstN in viewDidLoad. How are you giving firstN its value?

Comment: firstN is a global variable that I fill with a delegate

Comment: Try replacing your WPCustomLabel with a UILabel, and see if it works then. That's the only thing I did differently that I think would make a difference.

Comment: it does not work either..I could fixed it using UIColor global Variable.. I know is not the best way, but at least it works

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should always use setters: self.validLabel.tewtColor = [UIColor redColor];

Also, you should do this configuration at cellForRowAtIndexPath: time, which is called by reloadData